# QFileSystemWatcher does not emit fileChanged() in console application

Tags: c++, qt, console, qfilesystemwatcher

in my files *console.h/.cpp* i have a small class which just asks the user to type in some text and then just prints the text again until the user enters "quit" (see method `consoleMain()`). However, in *main.cpp* I also have a
`QFileSystemWatcher` which watches the file *MyTextFile.txt* and calls `Console::slotFileChanged(QString)` whenever the text file changes. Unfortunately the `QFileSystemWatcher` does not work. `Console::slotFileChanged(QString)` is never executed when I change the text file. As far as I know, `QFileSystemWatcher` works only if the main event loop has been started and this is also the case in my code.
When I disable the `QTimer::singlaShot` in the *main.cpp* and replace it by `emit console.signalStart()`
the main event loop will not be entered, but I see the message of the `QFileSystemWatcher` ("File changed!") **after I enter "quit"**.
The question is: Is it possible to let the user interact with the console and let the FileWatcher emit the signal when the text file is changed in parallel?
(I've also tried to put the `QFileSystemWatcher` into the console class and creating it on the heap; unfortunately it didn't change anything)

Here is my code:

**console.h**

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>

class Console: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Console(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Console();

signals:

    void signalStart();
    void signalEnd();

public slots:

    void consoleMain();
    void slotFileChanged(QString text);
    void slotEmit();
};

#endif // CONSOLE_H
```

**console.cpp**

```
#include "console.h"

Console::Console(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
}

Console::~Console()
{
}

void Console::consoleMain()
{
    bool isRunning = true;
    std::string in;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        std::cout << ">" << std::flush;
        std::getline(std::cin, in);

        if (in.compare("quit") == 0)
            isRunning = false;
        else
            std::cout << "You have entered: " << in << std::endl;
    }

    emit signalEnd();
}

void Console::slotFileChanged(QString text)
{
    Q_UNUSED(text);
    std::cout << "File changed!" << std::endl;
}  

void Console::slotEmit()
{
    emit signalStart();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "console.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFileSystemWatcher watcher(&a);
    watcher.addPath("C:/MyTextFile.txt");

    Console console(&a);

    QObject::connect(&console, SIGNAL(signalStart()), &console, SLOT(consoleMain()));
    QObject::connect(&console, SIGNAL(signalEnd()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), &console, SLOT(slotFileChanged(QString)));

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &console, SLOT(slotEmit()));
    //emit console.signalStart();

    std::cout << "Enter main event loop now" << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You call `consoleMain` explicitly.  Until it finishes running, it runs.  As far as I know, Qt has little console support.  Possibly the easiest way to solve it would be to have one thread sitting on the console, and the main event loop running on a different thread, and have the console send messages to communicate with the main event loop?  Google finds http://stackoverflow.com/a/18889631/1774667 answer which seems to relay characters typed via messages, which you'd have to reconstitute manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is solved. I've tried Yakk's idea using different threads (thanks for the idea Yakk). I had to introduce a new subclass of `QObject` called `MyObject`. In its constructor I create the `Console` and a new `QThread` for the console object. The `QFileSystemWatcher` is created in *main.cpp* as well as  an instance of `MyObjcet`. See code below:

**myobject.h**

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include "console.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyObject();

private:

    QThread *thread;
    Console *console;

signals:

    void signalStart();

public slots:

    void slotFileChanged(QString text);
    void slotEnd();
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

**myobject.cpp**

```
#include "myobject.h"

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
    console = new Console;

    thread = new QThread(this);
    console->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    connect(this, SIGNAL(signalStart()), console, SLOT(consoleMain()));
    connect(console, SIGNAL(signalEnd()), this, SLOT(slotEnd()));
    emit signalStart();
}

MyObject::~MyObject()
{
    thread->quit();
    thread->wait();
}

void MyObject::slotFileChanged(QString text)
{
    console->displayChangedFileText(text);
}

void MyObject::slotEnd()
{
    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(&a);
    watcher->addPath("C:/MyTextFile.txt");

    MyObject *object = new MyObject(&a);

    QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)), object, SLOT(slotFileChanged(QString)));

    std::cout << "Enter main event loop now" << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

*console.h/.cpp* are unchnaged, only `Console::slotFileChanged(QString)` was replaced by `Console::displayChangedFileText(QString)`.