# How to get out of infinite while loop by pressing esc in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How to get out of infinite while loop by pressing esc in Qt?

```
while(1){
    //doing some task
    if(ESC_PRESSED)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Do you have console or GUI application? Do you use threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle keypress events in a Qt console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543313/how-to-handle-keypress-events-in-a-qt-console-application)

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with qt but in general I would guess that you have to register somewhere to recieve something like a `ESCKeyPressedEvent`. When you recieve the event you would do something like this:

```
bool esc_was_pressed = false;
void on_esc_pressed(){
    esc_was_presed = true;
}
```

and in your loop

```
while(!esc_was_pressed){
    //doing some task
}
```

Actually I think you will just recieve a `KeyPressedEvent` and have to do something like:

```
void on_key_pressed(KEY key){
    if (key == ESC_KEY) esc_was_pressed = true;
}
```